# Upgrade ZFS from 0.7.13 to 0.8.0 on CentOS Linux

Tags: centos, zfsonlinux

I have an CentOS 7.6 machine with zfsonlinux kABI-tracking kmod v.0.7.13 installed.

How can I upgrade ZFS to the newest version? `yum update` says that i´m up-to-date.
Thanks

Comment: ZFS 0.8.x was just released some days ago. I strongly advise you to wait before updating a production box.

Comment: Their plan is to release zfs-0.8.2 for general use on EL7.7 and up. See the developer's comment [here](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/pull/9161#issuecomment-534682816). 0.8.0 and 0.8.1 are available under zfs-testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wait for the zfsonlinux project to publish updated packages. If they don't do so in a reasonable time, then you open an [issue](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues) on their GitHub.

It appears they missed something. My Fedora boxes all were offered zfs 0.8.0 packages three days ago.

I also suggest you wait, though, as judging from the issues reported, this .0 release appears to have quite a few annoying bugs.